# AngularJS: Update URL without full page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm trying to get my app working so that I can update the URL but without re-loading the whole view. I simply want to update the model and change the URL to reflect the new item being displayed.

I'm using this solution to achieve this: http://joelsaupe.com/programming/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/

But I have a couple of issues with it:

1) The back/forward buttons on the browser no longer work - so I basically need to update the model when the URL changes and not just update the URL when the model changes..?

2) Once I've updated the URL without reloading the page, clicking on further links, such as menu options of the sort 'Books' no longer work. I can only get the navigation to work again by refreshing the page.

Does anyone have a solution to these problems? I would have expected that this sort of behaviour is common in a single page application, so it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

By the way, I'm using the angular-route module, but I'm happy to switch to angular-ui-router module if it makes life easier.

EDIT: Adding current code examples

I currently have something like this in the .config block of my main app module:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/books', {
        title: 'Books',
        templateUrl: CONFIG.static_url + '/html/books.html',
        controller: 'BooksCtrl',
    })
    .when('/book/:itemId', {
        title: 'Books',
        templateUrl: CONFIG.static_url + '/html/books.html',
        controller: 'BooksCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/books'
});
```

Then, in the run block, I have the code taken from the linked solution above:

```
    // prevent reloading of view if reload = false
    // TODO: fix issue where back button does not reload previous view
    // TODO: fix issue where menu links no longer load page after 
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function (path, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current,
                un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                    $route.current = lastRoute;
                });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
```

Finally, when I asynchronously change the model to load in a new item, I update the URL:

```
// update the url
$location.path('/book/'+id, false);
```

Comment: Why doesn't standard Angular routing work for you?

Comment: It works, but it reloads the entire view. My page is set up with panels down either side and a main panel in the middle. I don't need the side panels reloading when updating the main panel, and it's a relatively expensive process. I just want to be able to update the main panel, but also update the URL so it reflects what is being displayed (and for bookmarking / deep-linking).

Comment: Does https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router help you? On the website you will find good examples for doing things like you want to do.

Comment: And if you want to do more stuff you can have a look at:
https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras

Comment: I also had a problem where back/forward did not update the $location.path - which, in my case, was causing logical errors. The location bar & view would update, but the angular path never did. It was strange. To uglyHack around this issue, I set an iterator and observed if the view changed. Check out that solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800757/angular-location-not-updating-when-browser-back-is-used