# Angular $location not updating when browser back is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, back-button, angular-routing

Has anyone run across this behaviour? There isn't much mentioned about it, and the other posts are different in nature. This appears to be inconsistent w/ documentation about browser behaviour.

> Synchronizes the URL with the browser when the user
>
> - Changes the address bar.
> - **Clicks the back or forward button** (or clicks a History link).
> - Clicks on a link.
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#!

What happens:

- [Load page](http://pp.gocactus.com) - hash updates (http://localhost:9000/#/)
- Click 'Start' - update $location.$$path via function to update hash and load new view (http://localhost:9000/#/guide)
- **Tricky! User clicks back-button in browser, hash updates back to http://localhost:9000/#/ but debug tells me $location.$$path still thinks we are at $location.$$path = /guide** - logic based on location path doesn't work.

This is a watcher to on location to help debug:

```
// listen for the event in the relevant $scope
$rootScope.$on('locationChange', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);
});

//Call locationChange watch at anytime the page is loaded 
$scope.$emit('locationChange', $location.$$path);
```

Here's the routing:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/guide', {
        templateUrl: 'views/guide.html',
        controller: 'GuideController',
        controllerAs: 'guide'
    })
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "anytime the page is loaded"? the page is loaded only once, then with the router the controllers would be created and destroyed according to the path. Can you provide the code in which you emit the event?

Comment: Correct, the page is only loaded once whether you land at root or child route/view. $location.$$path is omitted in a function that is triggered at all app changes, yet does not update when you click around and then click browser back.

When and how does Angular track a back/forward button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved this:

```
var pop = 0;

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if (document.location.pathname === '/' && pop > 1) {
        pop = 0;
        document.location = 'http://localhost:9000/';
    }
    pop++;
};
```