# Browser back button not working in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, back-button

In my angular project the back button of the browser is not working for a particular page. When I click the button, to move from Career Landing page to Overview page, nothing happens.

For other pages, it is working fine.

What are the possible changes needed to be done for a favourable output ?

Comment: create your own directive using `$window.history.back()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular $location not updating when browser back is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800757/angular-location-not-updating-when-browser-back-is-used)

Comment: Are you using the angular ui router?

Comment: var pop = 0;

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if (document.location.pathname === '/' && pop > 1) {
        pop = 0;
        document.location = 'http://localhost:9000/';
    }
    pop++;
};

Comment: where to add this code to get the browser button go back...?